# Script to record a cell value remotely before it is erased by a constantly updating program Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, snapshot

*Let's start with the Set-up. I am working on a program that assigns employees inspections based on who is the closest from their last job. The issue however it this program uses the TODAY function, which constantly updates. This wouldn't be a problem except once it is no longer TODAY, the optimization loop I've created pulls new values, meaning that jobs now previous to the current date will show as blank in the inspector column. In other words, once a date moves into the past we will have no record of who was assigned to it, which makes following up very difficult.

**Here is what I need help to make happen.

At 5pm, I want cells in column E to take a snapshot of the value of the corresponding cells in column D for dates that equal TODAY.**

Ideally I want this to be a custom function so I can make it dependent on the cell reference of the date code for TODAY.
(Such As in Cell E2: IF(B2=TODAY,"CUSTOM FUNCTION CAUSING SNAPSHOT of D2 Triggering @ 5pm"," ")*

[Schedule Sheet Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuTw5.png)

Comment: If this is supposed to be a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), note that it must still be a proper question per [ask] and a separate answer per [answer].

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. While I am aware of the rules and suggestions, I do not understand which of the guidelines I have not met. Could you provide specific feedback for how this post falls short? I would prefer to not have my answer go unanswered and deleted as the original question was.

Comment: Most obviously: you haven't posted an actual answer. You have what looks to be an answer *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the problem I was seeking to solve. I after over a week of unassisted work, I was able to do what other posts and users deemed impossible without using App Scripts.**

SOLUTION, ENTERED IN COLUMN P

```
 =IF(O13="Automatic",IF($X$4<=L13+$Z$4,N13,P13),O13)
```

Column O gives me control of whether Column P displays the Automatically assigned inspector (Column N), or if it uses a Manually selected one, located in a dropdown menu of Column O.

X4 is a cell reference to a NOW() Function

Column L allows only dates

Z4 is a cell reference to a trigger time, which can be updated to any valid time.

Also note: To make this work, the spreadsheet settings must be adjusted. Make sure the timezone is correct. Enable iterative calculations. And set the spreadsheet to update on edit and by the minute.

**All of this comes together to form a cell reference that will defer to the manual assignment when used, but will otherwise actively reflect the contents of the corresponding cell in column N until the trigger time, where in the code loops back on itself, resulting in a snapshot of the value that remains even after the program erases the values in column N**